# Fixing a gap with silicone on shower base

Tags: bathroom, repair, shower

I recently discovered a problematic area in the shower base where the silicone peeled off and the gap was visible underneath the tiles.

Now I removed a bit more silicone left and right from the problematic spot and planning to put some new bathroom sealant on the gap.

Would that work ok?

Thanks
[image: gap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a good plan. Make sure the area is totally dry before applying the new sealer. Scrape the area with a single edge razor blade to remove all the old sealer and then wipe the area with some vinegar to remove any residue. Stuff some paper towel in the gap to make sure it's totally dry, then apply some quality silicone caulk to the gap. Check the rest of the tub for any other failed areas.

Comment: It may not be a bad idea to pull up all the old silicone caulk and replace it all. One failure might lead to more, and may as well take care of it all in one shot.